# Typescript error when casting

Tags: typescript, webpack, karma-runner

I'm running a seed project that runs Jasmine and Karma.
Everything is set up correctly.

Webpack starts the app "npm start"
But when I run "npm test" Webpack looks at a .ts file that then loads the .spec.ts files.
I get an error when running this code from the seed project

```
bundle is now VALID.
[32m06 10 2016 10:16:42.660:INFO [karma]: 
[39mKarma v0.13.22 server started at http://localhost:9876/

[32m06 10 2016 10:16:42.664:INFO [launcher]: 
[39mStarting browser PhantomJS
[32m06 10 2016 10:16:44.259:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: 
[39mConnected on socket /#YRouUOeCLSlLTu_KAAAA with id 23215732
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0)

ERROR
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
  at C:/Development/ScratchApp/ScratchApp/src/test.ts:4
```

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0)

The error is Unexpected token '<'
In the following  test.ts file

```
// this file is only being used by karma
require('phantomjs-polyfill')

requireAll((<any>require).context("./", true, /spec.ts$/));
function requireAll(r: any): any {
    r.keys().forEach(r);
}
```

Can some one see this syntax error?

Comment: Seems like you're trying to run typescript code. You should first compile the typescript code into javascript code and then run that.

Comment: Yes you are correct. The problem was more complicated then I posted here, due to source control losing mapping files (and definitions). WebPack was looking at the wrong source for some strange reason on a build server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part of this question is this:

```
at C:/Development/ScratchApp/ScratchApp/src/test.ts:4
```

This is why you get an unexpected token of '<', because your TypeScript file has `<any>` on the line starting `requireAll`. JavaScript does not expect to find type annotations, which is why they are all erased during compilation.

Update your runtime code to use the compiled file:

```
C:/Development/ScratchApp/ScratchApp/src/test.js
```